# UserControl: use custom property in the constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I've this issue:

I created a custom `UserControl` and I added this property:

```
public string TestString { get; set; }
```

and it's ok, in the Properties I'm able to edit it:

[image]

Now it's the issue: I need to read this property in the Constructor of my usercontrol: to simply test this I have this code:

```
public ucnTest()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show(TestString);
}
```

and when I go run I got this:

[image]

seems that during the constructor the value is not yet passed... how can I fix this?

PS: if I put the message in the load event it works:

```
private void ucnTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(TestString);
}
```

Comment: You've said the answer yourself: giving a value to the property in design mode will only assign it after the constructor has run. Simply put the value assignment into the constructor.

Comment: thanks.. and why in some old vs version this worked fine?

Comment: Test the property value in the `Load` event instead. The property of the UserControl, when set in a Form's designer, is set only after the UC is initialized. So, you won't find it already set in its constructor, but when it's being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF/UWP rule of thumb: all visual activities should be intended to happen not before `Loaded` event. Partially-loaded control can behave weirdly or even crash. So, popping a message box directly from the constructor is really-really bad idea from very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's happening, I suggest you look into the InitializeComponent() method of your forms constructor (or wherever you added your UserControl).

You should see, that the constructor of your UserControl is called, before the value you assigned in the designer is passed to your control.

If you really need to access the value in the constructor, you need to pass it as a parameter like so:

```
public string TestString { get; set; }
public ucnTest(string myStringValue)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TestString = myStringValue;
    MessageBox.Show(TestString);
}
```

and then you need to pass `"YourString"` to the constructor in the InitializeComponent() method.

EDIT:
Added the property to the code

Comment: thanks @cmos, but how can I pass a property to the constructor?

Comment: thanks, but how can I call the constructor? I need to change the code under `Designer.cs`

Comment: In your Designer.cs there should be a line where the basic constructor of the UserControl is called. Here you can pass your string. As far as I know, you won't be able bind it to a Property in the designer, if that is what you are looking for.